# What is a good, eloquent way to describe something that was made with care?

Tags: adjectives

In a piece I am working on, I originally wrote "what I carefully crafted over countless weekends," but even with the alliteration I feel like it doesn't flow well, is there another way to convey the same message? I am building up the idea that it took effort and care to make because the object actually breaks in the next line. Thank you!

Comment: Meticulously, painstakingly, lovingly...  I see nothing wrong with carefully though.

Comment: You may be feeling that the split infinitive "I carefully crafted" is a bit clumsy. We used to be taught that split infinitives were wrong, but they are, sometimes, a bit inappropriate. Try "I crafted carefully over several weekends.

Comment: I created/crafted with utmost care/devotion? Please provide an example sentence showing the use of the word. You can keep place of the word blank or mark it with X.

Comment: Tolkien: *"So passed the sword of the Barrow-downs, work of Westernesse. But glad would he have been to know its fate who wrought it slowly long ago in the North-kingdom when the Dúnedain were young, and chief among their foes was the dread realm of Angmar and its sorcerer king. No other blade, not though mightier hands had wielded it, would have dealt that foe a wound so bitter, cleaving the undead flesh, breaking the spell that knit his unseen sinews to his will."*

Answer (score -1):

FYI: *painstakingly crafted* returns many online results, as expected.

BTW: Perhaps adding *had* would help, assuming the verb will be a synonym of *broke.*

*what I had so carefully crafted, over countless weekends, crumbled…*

Sources:

1. WordHippo
2. Thesaurus.com

Comment: Look at the site help/guide to see what makes a good answer. Mere assertion is not sufficient.